# jQuery slideToggle + bounce effect at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a top menu slideToggle and bounce at the same time after a #content div has loaded.  Here's the correct code with out the bounce:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#content").hide();

    $("#nav-top").hide();

        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#content").fadeIn(3000, function() {
                $("#nav-top").slideToggle(function() {
                    $("#music-player").fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
    });
});
```

-- I'm trying to do it on the $("#nav-top").slideToggle(function() {

So, does any know how something like this would be achieved?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include jQuery UI's [bounce](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce) effect, and chain the calls to slideToggle and `effect("bounce")` together:

```
 $("#nav-top").slideToggle(function() {
      $("#music-player").fadeIn(1000);
 }).effect("bounce",300);
```

You can see it working in [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeY8y/7/). Although I actually prefer the effect without the bounce :)